# Compile`GetElement for tensors of rank 1 and 2

Tags: performance-tuning, syntax, compile

Consider some data `momvals`, `mzvals` and functions `phVal`, `thVal`:

```
phVal[px_, py_] = 
  If[py > 0, 
   ArcCos[px/(\[Sqrt](px^2 + py^2))], -ArcCos[
     px/(\[Sqrt](px^2 + py^2))]];
thVal[px_, py_, pz_] = ArcCos[pz/(\[Sqrt](px^2 + py^2 + pz^2))];
momvals = RandomReal[{0, 50}, {10^4, 3}];
mzvals = Join[RandomReal[{0.2, 0.5}, {1000, 1}], 
   RandomReal[{1, 100}, {1000, 1}], 2];
```

Next, let us consider some code using the data and functions to check whether some condition is true:

```
codetest = 
 Hold@Compile[{{momvals, _Real, 1}, {mzvals, _Real, 2}}, 
      Module[{p1vals, p2vals, p3vals, thvals, phvals, count, mval, 
        Eval, zval},
       count = 0;
       p1vals = Compile`GetElement[momvals, 1];
       p2vals = Compile`GetElement[momvals, 2];
       p3vals = Compile`GetElement[momvals, 3];
       thvals = thVal[p1vals, p2vals, p3vals];
       phvals = phVal[p1vals, p2vals];
       Do[
        mval = Compile`GetElement[mzvals, i, 1];
        Eval = Sqrt[mval^2 + p1vals^2 + p2vals^2 + p3vals^2];
        zval = Compile`GetElement[mzvals, i, 2];
        count += 
         Boole[0.1 < thvals < 0.2 && 0.11 < phvals < 0.22 && 
           4 < Eval < 15 && 30 < zval < 45], {i, 1, Length[mzvals], 
         1}];
       count], CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", 
      RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}] /. DownValues@phVal /. 
   DownValues@thVal // ReleaseHold
```

The code treats `momvals` as a tensor of rank 1 and `mzvals` as a tensor of rank 2, and then for each value performs `Length[mzvals]` evaluations of a boolean condition.

My question is the following: may the `Do` routine potentially slow down the evaluation compared to some alternative code in which `mzvals` would be treated as a tensor of rank 1 (so instead of `` Compile`GetElement[mzvals, i, 1] `` one would use `` Compile`GetElement[mzvals, 1] ``)? Or `codetest` already looks fine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this aspect is quite fine. You can check the C-code with `ExportString[codetest, "C"]`. These two calls to `` Compile`GetElement `` are translated into the following:

```
{
mint S0 = I0_12 - 1;
S0 = S0 * D1[1] + (I0_1 - 1);
R0_ 2 = P1[S0];
}
[...]
{
mint S0 = I0_12 - 1;
S0 = S0 * D1[1] + (I0_2 - 1);
R0_1 = P1[S0];
}
```

Here, `I0_12` is the loop index `i`, `P1` is the array `mvals`, `D[1]` is the second dimension of `mzvals` , and `I0_1 = 1` and `I0_2 = 2`. A human being would write this loop rather like

```
const mint d_0 = D1[0];
const mint d_1 = D1[1];
for( mint j = 0; j < d_0; j += d_1 )
{
    R0_1 = P1[j  ];
    R0_2 = P1[j+1];
    [...]
}
```

and thus avoid some of the integer arithmetic, in particular the integer multiplication. But maybe the C compiler is able to simplify this. Also keep in mind that modern CPUs have separate arithmetic units for floating point and integer arithmetic which can be used concurrently (instruction level parallelism). This means that reducing the amount of integer operations does not necessarily decrease the runtime.

One can try to avoid at least one of the integer multiplications by doing

```
{mval, zval} = Compile`GetElement[mzvals, i];
```

but I am not sure whether this would improve the runtime. Depending on how it is really translated, it could have also the diametral effect.

---

But I think there are some other details that could be improved. For example `p1vals^2 + p2vals^2 + p3vals^2` needs to be computed only once.
Similarly, the check `0.1 < thvals < 0.2 && 0.11 < phvals < 0.22`  also has to be done only once. And one can get rid of not-so-inexpensive `Sqrt` entirely. In plain C-code, I would also replace the powers `p1vals^2` by `p1vals * p1vals` (the C function `pow` is super expensive), but from code inspection I know that *Mathematica* does it on its own.

Here my suggested edits:

```
codetest = 
 Hold@Compile[{{momvals, _Real, 1}, {mzvals, _Real, 2}}, 
      Module[{p1vals, p2vals, p3vals, thvals, phvals, count, mval, zval, square, a, b},
       count = 0;
       p1vals = Compile`GetElement[momvals, 1];
       p2vals = Compile`GetElement[momvals, 2];
       p3vals = Compile`GetElement[momvals, 3];
       thvals = thVal[p1vals, p2vals, p3vals];
       phvals = phVal[p1vals, p2vals];
       square = p1vals^2 + p2vals^2 + p3vals^2;
       a = 16. - square;
       b = 225. - square;
       If[
        0.1 < thvals < 0.2 && 0.11 < phvals < 0.22,
        Do[
          mval = Compile`GetElement[mzvals, i, 1];
          zval = Compile`GetElement[mzvals, i, 2];
          count += Boole[a < mval^2 < b && 30. < zval < 45.];
          , {i, 1, Length[mzvals], 1}];
        ];
       count
       ],
      CompilationTarget -> "C",
      RuntimeOptions -> "Speed",
      RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}
      ] /. DownValues@phVal /. DownValues@thVal // ReleaseHold
```

By the way: If you know `Length[mzvals]` at compile time, then it might be a good idea to insert the known value for `Length[mzvals]` in the `Do`-loop. If the C compiler knows its value it can simplify the loop considerably.